# C++ include loop. Can't use forward declarations

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, include, forward-declaration

I want to do something like this, running from main():

Main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
int main(){
    A* a = new A();
    B* b = new B(a);
    b->render();
    return 0;
```

A.h

```
class B;
class A {
public:
    void renderObject(B* b);
}
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
void renderObject(B* b) {
    int* data = b->data;
    //do something with data
```

B.h

```
class A;
class B {
public:
    A* a;
    B(A* a);
    int* data;
    void render();
}
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
B(A* a) {
    this->a = a;
    //something that write stuff to data.
}
void render() {
    a->renderObject(this);
}
```

Is this kind of coding possible? What can I do so that both can reference to both?

Comment: Would you like to give details on the problem you encounter?

Comment: It is possible and you're close to having solved your [circular header dependency issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). All what's missing: `A.cpp` as well as `B.cpp` have to `#include "A.h"` _and_ `#include "B.h"` (because both translation units need to know `class A` and `class B` in detail).

Comment: @Scheff Oh yes, both. You won't mind if I extend my answer accordingly?

Comment: I think you are missing some `A::` and `B::`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this line in A.cpp you need more than "it is a class", the information provided by a forward declaration.
I.e. in this file you need an additional

```
#include "B.h"
```

Similar for B.cpp, it needs to include A.h for the contained code.
(Thanks, Scheff.)

And, at least if only looking at the shown code, you do not really need to include A.h in A.cpp. This already changes if you add the seemingly missing `A::` and the rest of the actual file very likely needs it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Will accept the answer when I can. Although what can you do if both classes are template classes? Aren't template classes needed to be defined inline? But in this case, they'll need to be defined separately. I'm just wondering 

Comment: In my experience templates can only be defined in headers. The implementation has to be in the header, too. For details please create a separate queastion on that, if you do not find it answered elsewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "Will accept the answer when I can."? As far as I know, after the already elapsed time you should be able. Is there an obstacle I am unaware of? But take your time anyway. Waiting for a possibly better answer is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: Yeah it's the waiting for time as I'm "new" here.

Comment: I thought it was 5 minutes. Probably longer than that ... No problem, I simply have misunderstood something. Have fun.